# Prove that for any prime p, there is a complete set of mod p residues {q1, . . . , qp}, where each qi is prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that for any prime p, there is a complete set of mod p residues {q1, . . . , qp}, where each qi is prime. I used the theorem {a, a+n, a+ 2n, . . .} contains infinitely many primes if gcd(a, n) = 1 but haven't got much progress. Any comment will be helpful!

Comment: For a fix $i=1,\dots, p-1$. You have that $\{i,i+p,i+2p,\dots\}$has a prime. So, make $q_i$ such a prime, i.e. $q_i=i\mod p$.

Answer (score 2):

That $q = i \pmod{p}$ means that $p \mid (q-i)$, or equivalently that there is a $k$ such that $q = pk + i$. Now if $0 < i < p$, you can apply your theorem. If $i = p$ (or equivalently, $i = 0$) then clearly the only prime that can work is $p$ itself -- but indeed that does work.

Answer (score 1):

You know that $a,a+n,a+2n,\ldots$ contains infinitely many primes if $\gcd(a,n)=1$. This is Dirichlet's Theorem on Arithmetic Progressions. We simply set $n=p$ and $a=r$ where $r \neq 0$ is some residue modulo $p$. Clearly, we have $\gcd(r,p)=1$ as $p$ is prime, and thus, for each residue $r$, we can find some prime $q_r$ in the arithmetic progression. Now, for $r=0$, just set $q_0$ to be $p$, as $p \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. This completes our proof!

Answer (score 1):

The theorem you mentioned (Dirichlet's theorem) gives the result. Since every $r \in {1,\dots, p-1}$ is relatively prime to $p$ the theorem says there is a prime $q_r$ that is of the form $q_r= np+r$. So $q_r\equiv r \mod p$. Add $p$ to the set and you have a complete set.